# The set of eigenvalues is compact

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis

I saw some posts about it, but with a lot of other assumptions and, honestly, they did not help. The problem is:

> $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, with $d \in \mathbb{N} \backslash\{0\}$. Show that $Eig(S):=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \lambda \text{ is eigenvalue of some }A \in S\}$ is compact if $S$ is compact.

My attempt: Since $S$ é compact, is closed and bounded. Since $S$ is closed, then, $Eig(S)$ is closed, once every $\lambda \leq d\cdot\max_{1\leq i,j\leq d}|a_{ij}|$. However, my problem begins on showing that is closed. I thought about showing that there is some Gershgorin disks disjoint from other and, then, the set of eigenvalues equals to the unioun of the Gershgorin disks, that are closed, but I do not found a way to show it. Also, I know that it can be shown that any convergent sequence converges to an elemento of $Eig(S)$, but I could not show it too.

Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A_nx_n=\lambda_n x_n$with $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$. Suppose $\lambda_n \to \lambda$. Then there is  subsequence $(A_{n_k})$ of $(A_n)$ converging to some $A \in S$. Now extract a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ converging ot a unit vector $x$. Then we get $Ax=\lambda x$ in the limit so $\lambda$ is an eigen vector of some elmnent of $S$.

Comment: Do you mean $||x_n||=1$, instead of $||x||_n=1$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: +1. Your solution is quite better than my idea using Gershgorin disks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already have it’s bounded.

You can consider $f(S,x)=|S-xI|$ as a continuous function from $R^{d\times d} \times R$ to $R$. Let $p(S,c)=c$ be the projection from the product space to $R$. We care about $p(S\times R \cap f^-1(0))$. The singleton set 0 is closed, so $f-1(0)$ is closed, so $S\times R \cap f^. It’s also bounded, so it’s compact, so it’s image is compact, so the set of zeroes of any characteristic polynomial of matrices in S is compact.